# why the function is not waiting until promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm using below code to return string from the method if the http promise is resolved but control is not waiting until promise is returned and i'm seeing return object is method method in the switch.Could anyone please tell me what mistake i'm doing here!!

controller has below logic:

```
var status=function(action){
switch(action)
{
case 'create':
                return $scope.submitdata();
                break;
default: alert();
}

$scope.submitdata=function()
{
service.postdata($scope.formdata)
    .success(function(data){
     $scope.response=data;
       return 'SUCCESS';
     })
    .error(function(error){
          Console.log(error);
          return 'FAILURE';
     })
```

}

Service method:

```
this.postdata=function(data){
return $http.post(URL,DATA);
}
```

Comment: You can't return a value from a async callback function... you need to use a callback based processing

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: If you use a promise API, then you can chain the result using a then function. Or you can try a callback pattern.

Comment: How is `Postdata` used?

Comment: You're best option would probably be to return the promise because it's async so you can't just return it's result but you can set the function to return the promise and resolve the promise in your later code.

Comment: If you want to use promises, you'll need to `return` them. And you should banish `success` and `error`, use `then` and `catch` instead (which actually work like you expect).

Comment: Your method names are totally convoluted. There's `submitdata`, `Postdata` and `postdata`, but I can't see which is called where. Can you please [edit] your question to fix these?

Comment: @Bergi  sorry for the confusion..I have edited the question..please let me know if that make sense!!

Comment: @ArunPJohny  I update the question..basically I'm setting returned data in the scope and I just want to return the status to inform the caller function that data posted successfully. If you could provide any sample example that would be great help. Thanks!!

Comment: @Vicky see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call for an example of how to handle this case

Answer (score 1):

The `.success` and `.error` methods **ignore** return values.

Also parameter values are *case sensitive*.

```
this.postdata=function(data){
    //THIS
    return $http.post(URL,data);
    //return $http.post(URL,DATA);
}
```

> ### Deprecation Notice<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)</sup>
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `.success` and `.error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `.then` method instead.

---

```
$scope.submitdataPromise = function() {
    return service.postdata($scope.formdata);
});

$scope.submitdataPromise
  .then(function onFulfilled(response){
    $scope.data = response.data;
    //return data for chaining
    return data;
}).catch(function onRejected(response){
    console.log(response.status);
    //throw to chain error
    throw response;
});
```

The `submitdataPromise` function immediately returns a *promise*. The promise is a container for *future* results of the XHR resolved either fulfilled or rejected. Those results can be retrieved by registering functions with the `$q` service to be invoked upon resolution.

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - data – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - status – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
> - config – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - statusText – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.
>
> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Note that if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it, meaning that the error callback will not be called for such responses.

-- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)

Comment: Thank u for the reply.. I tried using then in the controller instead of success but saw the similar behavior so just wondering if you could provide me some sample code snippet!!